# Python: Packages that are not relevant for project

Tags: python

When I create a virtualenv for a Python project, it get's "polluted" by packages that I install for my convenience (like iPython or other packages that my editor "VS Code" depends on, like "pylint").

But these packages are not relevant for my project. So if I do `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, I see that only a few packages are relevant for my project.

What is the best way to clean up?

- Install those packages in a global context so that I can use them in every project I begin? or
- Do a `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, then edit the requirements file and remove not needed packages?

Comment: If you do not want the `pip` to install the packages that are not relevant to your project, the only solution that comes to my mind is you not doing `pip freeze > requirements.txt` and installing packages & creating `requirements.txt` files manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What we do here:

First we have the project's requirement file - the one used for deployments. This is not built using pip freeze but manually edited so it only contains relevant packages.

Then we have the "dev" requirement file with packages that are only useful for development but are required to work on the project  (linters, additionnal testing stuff etc).

And finally each is free to maintain his own personal additional requirements (editor-related packages etc).

Note that using virtualenvwrapper (which really helps for development installs) you define hooks that will install packages when you create a new virtual env.

Comment: Got any resources / books / recommendations for how to tackle this systematically?

Comment: Just the above and common sense (not using pip freeze to build the requirements file being a good start).

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://github.com/bndr/pipreqs) is an alternative solution for preparing `requirements.txt` manually.

The project I mentioned above prepares a `requirements.txt`
for your project based on the imports you did in your project's Python files.

Assuming all of your Python files in `myproject`, doing these in your terminal:

```
$ pip install pipreqs
$ pipreqs myproject
```

will generate a `requirements.txt` file for you.

This way, you can just `pip install -r requirements.txt` in your virtual environment instead of `pip freeze > requirement.txt` since you will have only the packages which are related to your project.